# Master - master replication not working

Tags: mysql, replication, wamp

I configured two `WAMP` servers running on different machines for master-master replication. I am using a `linksys` router for the network. I created a wireless network, but one of the server boxes doesn't have a `WIFI` so I used cable to connect it to the router. After the configuration, everything seem to be okay, but the servers don't seem to connect with each other as slaves. Below is the server status.

```
Variable               Value
Slave_IO_State:        Connecting to master
Master_Host:           192.168.1.100
Master_User:           master
Master_Port:           3306
Connect_Retry:         60
Master_Log_File:       mysql-bin.000001
Read_Master_Log_Pos:   95849
Relay_Log_File:        Chibuzo-PC-relay-bin.000001
Relay_Log_Pos :        4
Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
Slave_IO_Running:      Connecting
Slave_SQL_Running:     Yes
Replicate_Do_DB:       ticket
Replicate_Ignore_DB:    
Replicate_Do_Table:     
Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:    
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:    
Last_Errno:     0
Last_Error:     
Skip_Counter    0
Exec_Master_Log_Pos:    95849
Relay_Log_Space:    107
Until_Condition:    None
Until_Log_File:     
Until_Log_Pos:  0
Master_SSL_Allowed:     No
Master_SSL_CA_File:     
Master_SSL_CA_Path:     
Master_SSL_Cert:    
Master_SSL_Cipher:  
Master_SSL_Key:     
Seconds_Behind_Master:
```

Running the following query on server 1 with IP address 192.168.1.102, I got the following result

```
SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE Repl_slave_priv = 'Y';

+-----------+-------------------------+
| User      | host                    |
+-----------+-------------------------+
| root      | localhost               |
| root      | 127.0.0.1               |
| root      | ::1                     |
| master    | 192.168.1.100           |
+-----------+-------------------------+
```

For server 2 with IP 192.168.1.100

```
 +-----------+-------------------------+
 | User      | host                    |
 +-----------+-------------------------+
 | root      | localhost               |
 | root      | 127.0.0.1               |
 | root      | ::1                     |
 | master    | 192.168.1.102           |
 +-----------+-------------------------+
```

Here is part of the error log on 192.168.1.102

```
121230  1:23:29 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121230  1:23:29 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121230  1:23:29 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121230  1:23:29 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121230  1:23:29 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
121230  1:23:29 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121230  1:23:29 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121230  1:23:30 InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121230  1:23:31 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 5483034
121230  1:23:31 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3306
121230  1:23:31 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '::';
121230  1:23:31 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121230  1:23:31 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121230  1:23:31 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
121230  1:23:31 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.24-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
121230  2:33:12 [Warning] Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used; so replication may break when this MySQL server acts as a slave and has his hostname changed!! Please use '--relay-log=Chibuzo-PC-relay-bin' to avoid this problem.
121230  2:33:12 [Note] 'CHANGE MASTER TO executed'. Previous state master_host='', master_port='3306', master_log_file='', master_log_pos='4'. New state master_host='192.168.1.100', master_port='3306', master_log_file='mysql-bin.000001', master_log_pos='95849'.
121230  2:38:50 [Note] Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'mysql-bin.000001' at position 95849, relay log '.\Chibuzo-PC-relay-bin.000001' position: 4
121230  2:39:11 [ERROR] Slave I/O: error connecting to master 'master@192.168.1.100:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400, Error_code: 2003
130101  2:56:57 [Note] wampmysqld: Normal shutdown

130101  2:56:57 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
130101  2:56:58 [Note] Error reading relay log event: slave SQL thread was killed
130101  2:56:58 [Note] Slave I/O thread killed while connecting to master
130101  2:56:58 [Note] Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'mysql-bin.000001', position 95849
130101  2:57:00 [Warning] wampmysqld: Forcing close of thread 1011  user: 'root'

SHOW binary LOGS;
```

On 192.168.1.102

```
 +------------------+---------------+
 | Log_name         | File_size     |
 +------------------+---------------+
 | mysql-bin.000001 |  1455         |
 | mysql-bin.000002 |   236         |
 | mysql-bin.000003 |  6417         |
 | mysql-bin.000004 | 12755         |
 +-----------+----------------------+
```

On 192.168.1.100

```
 +------------------+---------------+
 | Log_name         | File_size     |
 +------------------+---------------+
 | mysql-bin.000001 |  96096        |
 | mysql-bin.000002 |  91695        |
 | mysql-bin.000003 |  48773        |
 +------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Seems like a network connection problem. Perhaps firewall is blocking connections? Are you able to connect to MySQL from one server to another?

Comment: @redguy With the same network, I can use a web application on either WAMP servers from other workstations on the network.

Comment: Whenever you start replication and get `Slave_IO_Running: Connecting` and `Slave_SQL_Running: Yes`, that quickly indicates a connectivity issue. The only way to know what is to check the error log. Please run `SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user WHERE Repl_slave_priv='Y';` and post it in the question (not as a comment).

Comment: Since you are using WAMP, MySQL for Windows may not allow you to print or copy the error log. Please run `net stop mysql`, copy and paste the last 20 lines of the error log into the question (not as a comment), then `net start mysql` .

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I've edited the question as you suggested. Thank you.

Comment: Please run `SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user WHERE Repl_slave_priv='Y';` on the Master and show that result please.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I've ran the query and edited the question to reflect the result. Thank you.

Comment: Please run `SHOW BINARY LOGS;` on 192.168.1.100 and post that output. Also, please tell me if the error log lines you posted came from 192.168.1.100 or 192.168.1.102.

Comment: Are Master and Slave running the same version of MySQL? If not, please run `SELECT VERSION();` on both servers and post output.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA yes, master and slave are running the same version of MySQL. Which is version 5.5.24

Comment: I had same problem and after checking my firewall access list and allow access for mysql the problem solved.

Answer (score 6):

In your Error Log :

```
[ERROR] Slave I/O: error connecting to master 'master@192.168.1.100:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400, Error_code: 2003
```

**Error_code: 2003** : The error (2003) Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server' (10061) indicates that the network connection has been refused. You should check that there is a MySQL server running, that it has network connections enabled, and that the network port you specified is the one configured on the server.

Try to connect from one server to the other with your "master" account :

On 192.168.1.100 :

```
mysql -h 192.168.1.102 -u master -p
```

On 192.168.1.102 :

```
mysql -h 192.168.1.100 -u master -p
```

Check, your **firewall**, try to **ping** and other stuff in relation to network communication...

Max.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried connecting as you suggested, I got the error 'ERROR 2003'. MySQL server is running and the port is the usual 3306. I checked my firewall, but WAMP/MySQL wasn't among the list.

Comment: From Bill Karwin, "90% of the time, this error is due either to the MySQL Server not running, or else firewall configuration on the Windows server blocking access on port 3306 (or whatever port your MySQL instance is configured to use)."

Comment: Thank you. Please how can I unblock access on port 3306?

Comment: Probably more like 99% of the time it's either not running or something's blocking port 3306. I think this is the third time I've hit this answer, and double-checking, it's always the firewall. D'oh!

Answer (score 3):

I have a suggestion

On the Slave run the following:

```
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO
MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001',
MASTER_LOG_POS=95849;
START SLAVE;
SELECT SLEEP(15);
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
```

This will reset all relay logs and attempt to connect from the log file and position from the error message. If you get `Slave_IO_Running: Connecting`, there are two scenarios to investigate

SCENARIO #1 : The binlog `mysql-bin.000001` on 192.168.1.100 might be corrupt.

You could verify this by running

```
mysqlbinlog --start-position=95849 mysql-bin.000001 > binlog_stuff.txt
```

Examine `binlog_stuff.txt` to see if contains clean statements or errors from the the binlog dump.

SCENARIO #2 : The binlog `mysql-bin.000001` on 192.168.1.100 is from a newer version of MySQL

- Replication from MySQL 5.0 to MySQL 5.1 is allowed
- Replication from MySQL 5.0 to MySQL 5.5 is allowed
- Replication from MySQL 5.1 to MySQL 5.5 is allowed
- Replication from MySQL 5.5 to MySQL 5.1 is not allowed
- Replication from MySQL 5.5 to MySQL 5.0 is not allowed
- Replication from MySQL 5.1 to MySQL 5.0 is not allowed
- I have discussed this before

  - [MySQL master binlog corruption](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12530/mysql-master-binlog-corruption/12531#12531)
  - [Mysql master-master replication auto flush old logs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11487/mysql-master-master-replication-auto-flush-old-logs/11488#11488)

## ALTERNATIVE

You could see if skipping to the next binlog would help

```
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO
MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000002',
MASTER_LOG_POS=107;
START SLAVE;
SELECT SLEEP(15);
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
```

If you get the same errors, you can undo it with

```
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO
MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001',
MASTER_LOG_POS=95849;
START SLAVE;
SELECT SLEEP(15);
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll do that now, but just to remind you, it's a master-master replication. I'll give you feed back soon.

Comment: good point that versions of mysql do matter.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes your master server blocks any incomming connections after many unsuccessful attempts. It happens often after testing for other connection related issues.

Anyway try flush-hosts on your master server:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p flush-hosts
```

then restart slave:

```
service mysql restart
```

and check if connected:

```
tail -30f /var/log/mysql/error.log
```